# Grabbing multiple tables with pd.read_html

Tags: python, pandas, html-table

I am trying to grab table data for company financials from google finance. Here is my code:

```
    url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=googl&fstype=ii'
    dfs = pd.read_html(url, flavor='html5lib')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    for df in dfs:
        print(df)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
```

However, what this returns when I print(df) is all the table data but whats saves to excel is just the table for quarterly data for the income sheet. Does anyone know why not all the data is being saved to excel? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the program is overwriting each dataframe in the same worksheet/position as it goes through the loop.

For will need to write each dataframe to a new worksheet or position each one within the same worksheet.

See these examples from the XlsxWriter docs:

- [Pandas Excel with multiple dataframes](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)
- [Pandas Excel dataframe positioning](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_positioning.html)